# Where to put 3rd party servlet in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I wish to use the barcode generator from http://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/main.html on `Glassfish 3.x`. I contacted them and they have no idea.

Their documentation states: (note that I deliberately put a space after http: to stop it being a link)

> Copy folder barcode, under BarcodeLib_JavaBarcode_Trial (or  BarcodeLib_JavaBarcode_Production), to your java servlet container like Tomcat.
>   Restart Tomcat, and test your installation, open web browser and navigate to:
>   http: //YourDomain:Port/barcode/ linear?Data=123456789&Type=CODE128

The unzipped folder containing their jar is: `\barcode\WEB-INF\lib\barcode.jar`.
I understand enough that it should not go in the `WEB-INF\lib\` on `Glassfish`.
I tried it in the:

```
C:\glassfish31\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
```

`-folder` but the suggested link did not work.

Is this the right place for it and if it is, is the http: `//YourDomain:Port/barcode/linear?Data=123456789&Type=CODE128` address the correct way to access it there?

Thanks in advance...